# Сломана верстка в профиле участника

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189741/cobalt?tab=topactivity

Баг воспроизводится на:

- Firefox 40.0.3
- Chrome 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)
- Opera 31.0.1889.174
- Safari Version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, слишком длинных строк много и их никто не фиксит. `на этой -> за`

Comment: Тоже видал, поленился репортить. Кажется, проявляется, только если «на этой неделе» написано. Сильно длинно, наверно.

Comment: По большому счёту, это проблема фиксированных длин и смещений в вёрстке. Вёрстка должна автоматически подстраиваться под длинные строки. Не поверю, что в HTML нету layout manager'а.

Comment: @Vlad Ну если не переносить её на следующую строчку тогда она заденет не то что вверху/внизу, а то что справа. Если сделать автоматический размер, тогда от длинной строки поедет все остальное. Верстка это боль и страдание. Проще просто один раз собраться с силами, взять и укоротить все длинные строки, для этого даже не нужен доступ к шаблонам. А 1 вопрос на мете на 1 баг верстки это реально порочная практика. Так вы вообще ничего не добьетесь и оно так и будет болтаться там еще года два.

Comment: @igumnov: Хм. Я бы сделал ограниченный размер по горизонтали и автоматический по вертикали. И выровнял «лучшая метка» со «следующая привилегия». Вроде ж нормально?